# How to Open Clickable Url in MFMailComposer

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, gmail, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I am using the Following piece of code

```
if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
        {
            MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
            picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;
            [picker setSubject:@"Check out"];
            UIImage *morphedImage = [sharedSingleton getCopy];
            NSData *myData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(morphedImage);
            [picker addAttachmentData:myData mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"RaceFaceImage"];
            [picker setMessageBody:@"I've given you a new look using my RaceFace iPhone application.  Check it out and have a good laugh.  I dare you to Race me, download the app here:<b>Sourish</b><a href='www.google.com'>itunesLink</a>" isHTML:YES];
            [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
            [picker release];
        }
        else
        {

        }
```

I am getting O/Pin this manner 
[image: MailCOmposer Output]

I want like when i click on the blue Text the particualr ur should get opened, how can i do that ??

Any Kind of Help is Highly Helpful
Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code

```
NSString *link = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.google.com"];
            [controller setMessageBody:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<p><font size=\"2\" face=\"Helvetica\"><a href=%@></br>%@</br></a></br></font></p>",link,@"Google"] isHTML:YES];
```

Hope it helps you....

Comment: Hey Prateek I tried with the code \, it wasn't working all that was happening is now i cannot take the cursor to middle of the Google Text, I would like when i click on the Google Text the google Link should get opened

Comment: If you are opening in mail composer, it will never work, try sending mail and then click on that link...

Comment: Yeah, When i am send the mail, in the inbox when i click on it its getting opened, but my requirement is like while opening mailComposer it has go to the Link